# XmlWriter in java

Tags: java, xml, import

I imported `javax.xml.*;`  and  `org.w3c.dom.*;` into my project  in hope to access the same XML methods that are used in [this tutorial](http://youtu.be/1JyYc2-f7Qs)(the tutorial is in other language, they imported XML by `using System.XML;`) however when i try to use:

```
 XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FilePath);
```

It cannot find class XmlWriter and both imports are marked as unused. Should i import something else? java XML tutorials dont mention this XmlWriter or the Create method. Do the same functions even exist in Java version of XML? Im total newb in XML so having the same methods they have in the tutorial video would be nice.

Comment: `using System.XML` seems like C#. Are you sure you are talking about Java?

Comment: Yes, im looking for an equivalent of this Objective-C function for Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java you can create XML files using DOMParser. This is a tutorial on how to create XML file using DOM parser [Java - XML file creation tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/)